# Strange behaviour number

Tags: php

I nave very simple array:

```
$plugin_temp_arr = array(
   'some_app_id' => 333475464566411
);
```

but when print_r($plugin_temp_arr ) i got

```
Array ( [some_app_id] => 3.3347546456641E+14 )
```

why that happens and how can avoid this?
and yes - if that be a string - got right value, but i want know- why this number has been converted to another format?

Comment: `php` can only store integers upto value `2147483647` `[PHP_INT_MAX]` after that it  shows them in powers of `e`

Comment: Its because of the range of integers. Rather use it as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except for Windows, which is always 32 bit. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

**32-bit builds of PHP:**

Integers can be from -2147483648 to 2147483647

**64-bit builds of PHP:**

Integers can be from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

Values outside of these ranges are represented by floating point values.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, if you store a number beyound the bound of integer (it's platform-depended, e.g. `32-bit`, `64-bit`), the number will be interpreted as a float instead.

You can use the `PHP_INT_MAX` constant to see the size of integer on your platform.

```
echo "PHP_INT_MAX: " . PHP_INT_MAX . PHP_EOL;
```